# bash: Is there a way to invoke bind commands (e.g. redraw-current-line) programmatically?

Tags: bash, readline

I've come across a number of explanations on how to map `redraw-current-line` to a keystroke using `bind`, but I would like to redraw the prompt for other reasons (e.g. timer, background job), without the user entering a keystroke. I assumed this would be easy but I can't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. Usually interactive solutions for *interactive* shell are enough. So what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634122/12298006 might be an answer, or maybe  `expect`, but this is probably an XY problem.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski A few use cases ... 1. update the prompt in response to tab completion 2. update the prompt in response to a background job completing 3. update the prompt due to a change in a realtime value (which might just be a specific case of #2). Note my 'command prompt' might be a multiline display with ANSI tricks.

Comment: @icarus Thanks ... I actually looked at `expect` earlier; the python code is new to me. But actually those seem like XY-type solutions, i.e. simulating a keystroke to trigger a bind function when I want to just call the bind function.

Comment: The question is why do you want to call a readline function, rather than say a termcap one (say to erase to the end of line). Readline is a library to read characters and then do things based on it. In the old days it was common to have a "status line" on the bottom of the screen, and commands run from the background would save the cursor position, switch to the status line, update it, then restore the cursor. You can set up multi-line scroll regions to do this with any ANSI terminal.  Obviously you know your problem better than us, perhaps you can edit you question to help us.

Comment: Thanks again ... I've been looking at ANSI codes and `tput`, and for my immediate use case -- an in-session 'watch window' that doesn't require screen/tmux/etc -- it is possible I'll have to give up on a PS1 implementation and go with an ANSI region. If so I will post that as a separate question. But there appear to be 100+ useful bindable readline commands, and I can think of fun reasons to invoke a lot of them, and my intuition was telling me that should be easy. But, maybe not.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but I haven't found anything satisfactory, so here are some workarounds.

#### `${PS1@P}`

In newer bash versions you can just print the prompt yourself with `echo "${PS1@P}"`. The `${var@P}` form of variable expansions means to expand prompt escapes inside a variable.

#### `kill -WINCH "$$"`

Another trick that you may try is to kill your shell with `SIGWINCH`. That will cause readline to redraw the prompt. Example:

```
$ (sleep 2; echo foo; sleep 2; kill -WINCH "$$") &
[1] 2295
<immediately press l and s; the "foo" text will mess up the current line>
$ lsfoo
<after 1s the prompt is redrawn again without the parasitic text>
$ ls
```

#### `ioctl(TIOCSTI)`

Yet another trick is bind some unused key to `redraw-current-line` as usual, and then simulate that key with the `TIOCSTI` ioctl (it still works without extra privileges on the *current* tty in Linux). But you would need either C, perl, python, etc for that:

```
$ bind '"\xff": redraw-current-line'
$ redraw_current_line(){ perl -e 'ioctl STDIN, 0x5412, $x = "\xff"' </dev/tty; }
$ (sleep 2; echo foo; sleep 2; redraw_current_line) &
.... same as in SIGWINCH example ...
```

This last trick is Linux-only; the ioctl number for `TIOCSTI` on other system that may support it is different.

---

**Note:** if someone thinks that I should `require "sys/ioctl.h"` instead of hardwiring the ioctl number: **No, I should not**. Even if it works by chance in *this* case, perl's `h2ph` is børked, and the `.ph` files should **not** be used:

```
$ perl -e 'require "sys/ioctl.ph"; printf "%x\n", TIOCGPTN()'
80005430
$ cc -include stdio.h -include sys/ioctl.h -xc - \
   <<<'int main(){printf("%lx\n",TIOCGPTN);}' -o /tmp/foo && /tmp/foo
80045430
```

Notice the extra bit on the real thing: `80045430` != `80005430`

Comment: Thanks ... I didn't know about `@P`; it looks interesting. This does not quite answer my question, and I'm not sure if it fits my specific use cases ... I believe it would lost the current line, and it would force me to know where the current prompt is so I could overwrite it properly. But if I can make it work I'll accept.

Comment: Try the SIGWINCH trick; it's more promising.

Comment: So `SIGWINCH` essentially forces a 'redraw' which among other things would redraw the prompt. That might work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the termios/TIOCSTI trick as well. I wasn't familiar with that, but it looks like that's the proper(est) way to programmatically emulate keystrokes in a terminal. I am still hoping to avoid faking keystrokes in favor of direct function invocation but this is good to know. Btw do I really want `</dev/tty' instead of `>/dev/tty`?

Comment: My perl command is explicitly using `STDIN`, so yes ;-) But if you know that the STDIN of your script is the controlling terminal (it's not in eg. `..|script`), you can omit the `</dev/tty` altogether.

Comment: Notice that for that (and most other) ioctl it doesn't matter if the fd is open in read-only mode.